# Implementing minimization method

Tags: python, c, algorithm, matlab, optimization

I have a function in 2 variables `x1,x2`

`f = 3*x1^2 + 4*x2^2 + 5*x1 + 6*x2 + 10`

Consider `x` is a row vector such that `x = [x5,x6]`, where `x5,x6` are components of the vector. If the notation is confusing, let us consider `x = [x1,x1]` but `x1,x2` can be any arbitrary components. The same argument holds for `y`.

Then I want to find `a` from `(x + ay)` such that it will minimize the `f`. `a` is real constant, `x` and `y` are vectors. This is explained above.

If this does not make sense, then let us consider `x,y` as a 1-dimensional arrays with 2 locations. So, x(1),x(2),y(1),y(2) be their components. Then I want to multiply array `y` by a symbolic variable `a`.

For example, `x=[4,5]`, `y=[-2,3]` then, `(x + ay) = (4,5) + a(-2,3) = (4-2a,5+3a)`. `a` is symbolic variable that is unknown here.

Substituting in `f1` (To be more clear, first argument in the definition of `f` `x1 = 4-2a`, second argument `x2=5+3a`)

`f1 = 3*(4-2a)^2 + 4*(5+3a)^2 + 5*(4-2a) + 6*(5+3a) + 10` ............(eq. 1)

Then function `f1` becomes unknown in one variable, `a` and can be minimized using 1D minimization algorithm, such as [golden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_section_search#Algorithm) section search, given an interval `[x_lower,x_upper]`.

My question is:

Given different `x`,`y`,

- How to evaluate `(x+ay)` and pass  (or substitute ?) it into function `f (eq1)`?
- How to create 'dynamic' function `f1`, as in eq. 1, to pass it to 1D minimization algorithm? By dynamic, I mean here is function `f1` will change every time for `x`,`y`.

I am interested in a low-level implementation of this problem (sticking to the basic features of a language as much as possible and without using language specific features or object oriented features) in python, MATLAB, C or any other language, but again in 'low level.' Can you suggest something?

UPDATE: I don't want to use symbolics from python, MATLAB or from any other language.

Comment: Is there a typo in you're first equation defining `f`? there is no `y` variable in it

Comment: @Abstracted No typo in `f`. It is function of `x,y` and then I want to pass `x+ay`. Is that answer your question?

Comment: your function is wrongly stated, it has x, x1, x2 and you are creating an argument of (x+ay). Please write your question carefully. Currently the math is wrong. Because (x+ay) is a single argument but f is a function of (x,x1,x2).

Comment: @percusse, corrected typo. f is function of (x1,x2). There is nothing wrong in (x+ay). x and y are row vectors (with 2 variables) as stated in problem.

Comment: @percusse. There was a typo in definition of `f` and I corrected it.  Apart from that, there is nothing wrong. Please don't abuse power and downvote for wrong reasons.

Comment: @de23edced I don't have power and didn't downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm rephrasing your question in my own words, because the question in its current form is confusing:

*You have a function `f(x1,x2) = 3*x1^2 + 4*x2^2 + 5*x1 + 6*x2 + 10`. `x1` and `x2` are the components of a 2D vector obtained from summing `x` with the product of `a` and `y`, where `x` and `y` are given vectors, and `a` is a scalar. You want to obtain the function that results from substituting this relation into `f`.*

Note that the notation is a bit confusing, so I will use instead `x = z+a*y`, where z (replacing the x you used) and y are the given vectors.

Let's define `f` as an anonymous function in Matlab (you could easily use a function file as well):

```
f = @(x) 3*x(1)^2 + 4*x(2)^2 + 5*x(1) + 6*x(2) + 10;
```

Note that I'm writing this differently than you did, i.e. `x(1)` and `x(2)` instead of `x1` and `x2`. This means that I am using components of a vector instead of two unrelated variables.

Then, let's write your equation involving `a` as a function as well:

```
g = @(a) z + a*y;
```

The function g(a) returns a vector for each value `a`, obeying `g(a) = z+a*y`.

Now you can do the substitution:

```
h = @(a) f(g(a))
```

`h` is the desired function that takes a as input and returns the value of `a` applied at the vector obtained from `z+a*y`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have rephrased it. Now it should be  less confusing.

Comment: Let me know if question still sounds confusing.

Comment: @de23edced Your question is still confusing. Is my rephrasing of your question correct? Did my answer satisfy your needs?

Answer (score -1):

you can use eval convert string to function

```
f = 'x+a*y'
x = 4
y = 3
for a in xrange(3):
    print eval(f)

output:
4
7
10
```